# Avoid overhead of passing data between shared libraries

Tags: c++, qt

In **1st** shared library, data for 3D coordinates is stored with `Point` structure:

```cpp
struct Point {

    float x{0}, y{0}, z{0};

};

std::vector<Point> *m_points;
```

In **2nd** shared library, data for 3D coordinates is stored with a `PointContainer` class

```cpp
class PointContainer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    // This is a sophisticated class ...

public:
    QVector3D m_coord;
}

QVector<PointContainer> *m_points;
```

---

To pass data from **2nd** shared library to **1st** one, I'm using a loop:

```cpp
std::vector<Point> data(number_of_points);
// Prepare the data in the structure needed by the 1st shared library
    for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_points; ++i) {
        float x = m_points->at(i).m_coord.x();
        float y = m_points->at(i).m_coord.y();
        float z = m_points->at(i).m_coord.z();
        Point point = {};
        point.x = x;
        point.y = y;
        point.z = z;
        data[i] = point;
    }
// Now pass data to the 1st shared library
```

`number_of_points` can be huge, and the above loop might be computationally expensive. Are there any ways to avoid the above loop? I tried to store data with same structure across shared libraries, but it requires a huge overhaul of the code. Not sure if there is any other option, just asking.

Comment: So, `PointContainer` inherits from `QObject` but each instance only manages a single `QVector3D`?  That seems *hugely* excessive.

Comment: Note that pointers to containers are *very seldom* needed. If you need to pass a container to a function (in a library or not) then use *references* instead.

Comment: @G.M. Right. I might remove the inheritance

Comment: As for your problem, considering that `QVector` support standard C++ iteration, I recommend you start by using [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with a suitable [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for the conversion. And don't use the (usually) bounds-checking `at` functions, and do simple inline initialization (which the compiler *maybe* can optimize it to anyway) of the `Point` objects.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile: `QVector<PointContainer> *m_points;`... *QObject* subclasses can't be copied, so you can't have them as values in a *QVector*. If you really meant to have a vector of pointers, then having a separate heap allocation for each point seems... not good.

Comment: @hyde It compiles for me!

Comment: Having the container itself won't cause compilation error it seems, but trying to actually put anything in it should give you error which says something like `'QObject::QObject(const QObject&)' is private within this context`.

Comment: @hyde I'm appending with such statements: `m_points->append(PointContainer(arg0, arg1, arg2));`

Comment: Then there's something different in your code, such as maybe you changed your code so you no longer subclass QObject.

Comment: @hyde I'm not sure, maybe something is different, however I clearly see such statements: `class PointContainer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT`

Comment: @hyde By the way, I'm using Qt 5.12.3 right now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193206/discussion-between-hyde-and-user3405291).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code would be a bit cleaner and a tiny bit faster:

```
std::vector<Point> data(number_of_points);
// Prepare the data in the structure needed by the 1st shared library
for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_points; ++i) {
    const auto& source = (*m_points)[i].m_coord;
    data[i] = {source.x(), source.y(), source.z()};
}
// Now pass data to the 1st shared library
```

If your number of points is *at a minimum* several tens of millions, you might speed up this loop with OpenMP or Intel TBB's parallel_for.